# How Get this Value

Tags: magento2

I create **ConfigProvider** in my payment method and getting result in console like this :

```
Array(1)
0:
CLC - Cisco Learning Credits: "CLC - Cisco Learning Credits"
test: "test"
```

and in js I am using this code:

```
return _.map(window.checkoutConfig.payment.training_voucher.transactionResults, function(value, key) {

                return {
                    'value': key,
                    'transaction_result': value
                }
            });
```

but its shows me object object need help